# Reliably present GTK window to user from minimized to taskbar

Tags: linux, debian, gtk, vala, kde-plasma

I'm trying to modify this app / source file:

https://github.com/mank319/Go-For-It/blob/master/src/view/MainWindow.vala

What this app is doing is that on timer expiring it shows GTK notification. What I would like it to do is to pop up from minimized and present window to user.

I've modified it so:

```
        try {
            this.deiconify();
            this.present();
            notification.show ();
        } catch (GLib.Error err){
            GLib.stderr.printf(
                "Error in notify! (break_active notification)\n");
        }
    }
    break_previously_active = break_active;
}

private void display_almost_over_notification (DateTime remaining_time) {
    int64 secs = remaining_time.to_unix ();
    Notify.Notification notification = new Notify.Notification (
        _("Prepare for your break"),
        _("You have %s seconds left").printf (secs.to_string ()), GOFI.EXEC_NAME);
    try {
        this.deiconify();
        this.present();
        notification.show ();
    } catch (GLib.Error err){
        GLib.stderr.printf(
            "Error in notify! (remaining_time notification)\n");
    }
}
```

i.e. I've added

```
this.deiconify();
this.present();
```

However, this only works *if and only if I do not switch to any other task in taskbar*. If I do that, the window does not pop up to present the window to me as if I clicked it on taskbar.

How can I make it pop up no matter what other app window is shown in main view?

GUI: KDE Plasma.
OS: Debian 9.7.

Comment: I don't know enought about Linux window managers, especially not about Kwin (or whatever window manager KDE uses these days), but on modern Windows you can't just bring a window to the foreground from a process that does not have the input focus: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090220-00/?p=19083/ Maybe there is an equivalent to AllowSetForegroundWindow on Linux?

Comment: Don't know KDE but on GNOME you cannot do this and I expect KDE is the same